# Why do edges and vertices seem to double and triple when modelling?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

Why does this happen?  Edges and vertices seem to have tripled.

[image]

I was really happy with my end result which is this below.

[image]

But now my mesh is a mess of lines and I do not know what I did wrong and how to clean it up.  All I used was a mirror modifier on the pommel to build a good equal skeleton fo it which I added once the skeleton was finished.

Comment: Hello :). Don't worry. This usually happens because *Mirror modifier* creates double vertices, if your model isn't cut perfectly in half. Just go to *mesh->clean up->merge by distance*. And before you use *Mirror modifier*, make sure your model has only one half.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to obtain a very smooth Handel by separating the pommel from it and redoing it since it was simple but your answer helped me clean the pommel lines even if I am having trouble shade smoothing it now.  I asked another question on it to try and understand why.